# How to have no tint colour on a UITabBar

Tags: objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

Using a custom image, when selected the background goes white and the tab image changes colour (done on a png). However when I leave the `[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:nil];` which is its default value, it goes blue. I have tried this:

```
[[UITabBar appearance] setSelectedImageTintColor:[UIColor clearColor];
```

However that makes it totally invisible! I have the png exactly how I need it, but I cant get rid of the colour. Is there a way to stop iOS from doing this?

Comment: Try [UIColor blackColor]

Comment: @doctordoder thanks for the suggestion however that just makes the icon go black.